# Moving from MySQL to MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Could somebody please point me in the right direction. I am in the process of making the transition from `MySql` to `MySqli`. Normally I would select from the database using th code below and it would allow me to easily use the column value as a working variable:

```
$SQLCommand = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = 'ok'";
$Data = mysql_query($SQLCommand);
$DataRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($Data);

$var1 = $DataRow["column1"];
$var2 = $DataRow["column2"];
$var3 = $DataRow["column3"];
$var4 = $DataRow["column4"];
```

I have researched how to do the `MySql` equivalent but I find theres a lot of different way using loops etc. Is there a like for like (for want of a better description) that does the same thing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I heartily suggest PDO instead of mysqli

Comment: What would be the PDO equivalent?

Comment: OP: see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of going with the flow, i care to suggest a PDO alternative

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, 'username','password'); 
              //$dsn is the connection string to your database.
              //See documentation for examples

//The next two rows are optional, but i personally suggest them to
//ease developing, debugging (the 1st) and fetching results (the 2nd)

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = :c1");
$stmt->bindValue(':c1', 'ok'); //This example is trivial and not necessary
                               //but it gains relevance when the bound value 
                               //is a variable
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); //if you expect a single row use fetch() instead

//do something with the results
```

You can read more about PDO here: [PDO manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

The biggest PDO advantage is that it's independent of the actual database in use by your application. If, by chance, you want to change database in the future, for example SQLITE or PostgreSQL, the only* change you have to make is your `$dsn` connection string

[*] True only if you used standard SQL queries and nothing vendor-specific.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It has well and truly pointed me in the correct direction. It all seems to make perfect sense due to your commenting within your code. +1

Comment: No. Not really maintained any more. Legal problem with development as it contains code from Microsoft and Oracle. mysqli is the way to go. How often do you change databases in production?

Comment: @chris can you please provide a citation to your claim?

Comment: One of the best PHP consultants in Germany told me this.

Comment: it sounds like word of mouth. Up to you if you want to trust this person, for me it's impossible as they could be literally anyone. Feel free to add your own answer to the question if you feel that mine is inadequate.

Comment: I trust people who work directly with Sebastian Bergmann, the creator of PHPUnit :-). lol.

Comment: That's indeed your prerogative :)

Answer (score 2):

A direct conversion would be:

```
$Data = mysqli_query($connection, $SQLCommand);
$DataRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Data);
```

The difference, other than the `i` is that `mysqli_query` requires the connection as an argument (as do most `mysqli_*` functions).

MySQLi also has an object oriented style:

```
$Data = $connection->query($SQLCommand); // assuming you created the $connection object
$DataRow = $data->fetch_assoc();
```

Answer (score 1):

They should be like

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
$SQLCommand = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = 'ok'";
$Data = $mysqli->query($SQLCommand);   
$DataRow = $mysqli->fetch_assoc($Data);
```

Try this [**LINK**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Do not forget to send a link as a parameter / use OOP style - mysqli object.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use mysqli prepared statement whenever you are using user inputs to prevent SQL injection:

See below code uses object oriented approach and prepared statement

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if (!$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test") ||
!$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE test(id INT, label CHAR(1))") ||
!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO test(id, label) VALUES (1, 'a')")) {
    echo "Table creation failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
/* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, label FROM test WHERE id = ?");

/* Prepared statement, stage 2: bind and execute */    
$id = 1;
//note below "i" is for integer, "s" can be used for string
if (!$stmt->bind_param("i", $id)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();

printf("id = %s (%s)\n", $row['id'], gettype($row['id']));
printf("label = %s (%s)\n", $row['label'], gettype($row['label']));
?>
```

Comment: Native prepared statements just unusable with mysqli. Ever tried something more complex than this simple example?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes I have tried and using more complex statements , I needed to implement a library which takes care of multiple placeholders in Mysqli, but I don't know why you down voted me ?
Am I the only one using mysqli ?